# Passing a large amount of data as a parameter Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I've a transformation, but I don't have any idea how I can solve my problem.

[image]

I have two different databases (ODS, DWH). I would like choose list for example 100000 records (ID) from DWH and pass this to clause: where id in (${parametr}) in ODS and DWH.

Someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is load the data that you want to filter on in a seperate table input, with a custom link value.

```
(for example "Select ID, 1 as link from dwh_table")
```

Then value lookup your mean stream with this table and retrieve the link value based on a shared id, set to 0 when the id-value is not found. This way you now have a custom filter value in your mean stream on which you can filter, select, or do whatever else you need to do with the 100.000 records.

(Keep in mind the answer to this question might change if the total set is incredibly big (like 10M+), but sizes are not mentioned in this question)